# Fatal error in function mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7, php-7.1

I'm trying to recode to work it with PHP7 but failing miserably. Could someone point me to the right direction?

Here's the error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/students/index.php on line 55
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/students/index.php:57 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/students/index.php on line 57

PHP Code:

```
<?php
            include("db.php");
            $result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM students");
            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $id = $test['UID']; 
                echo "<tr align='center'>"; 
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['UID']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['FirstName']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['LastName']. "</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['Marks']. "</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['RollNumber']. "</font></td>";    
                echo"<td> <a href ='view.php?UID=$id'>Edit</a>";
                echo"<td> <a href ='del.php?UID=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            mysql_close($conn);
            ?>
```

I have removed other unnecessary code and showing only the one which is creating error.

Comment: I closed an earlier question of yours http://stackoverflow.com/q/43707150/1415724 - I see you tried "something" but you can't just put in "one" mysqli_ function, the entire code needs to be using the same api; you can't mix `mysql_` with `mysqli_`. Many mysqli_ functions require a database connection to be the first argument. The duplicates contain reference links for you to look at and use that syntax.

Comment: Yeah. I have re-written everything. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome Elaine. I take it that you have gotten success now?

Comment: Yes. After a lot of reading :)

Comment: For those of you looking for solutions; I simply change all the `mysql` to `mysqli` and added `$conn` to lines such as `$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM students");` and it began to work like a charm :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved this by yourself Elaine, *cheers* :-)